# Testing - Executing a C++/CLR class project during creation

Tags: visual-c++, clr

I am attempting to create a C++/CLR class project and I wanted to know how would you test the class code that you wrote if there is no entry point (i.e) there is no main ? I am using VS2010 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to use a unit testing framework such as xunit or nunit.

Xunit seems to the most popular nowadays ...

http://xunit.codeplex.com/

This will give you a GUI to run unit tests or if you prefer, you can run tests from the command line.